# I want the "About me button to be on the top right hand side without moving the navigation bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my **CSS:**

```
    <style>
    .imageBox {

            float: right;
        }
        .imageBox .hoverImg {
           position: relative;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            display: none;
            margin-right: 100px;
        }
        .imageBox:hover .hoverImg {
            display: block;
        }
     ul{ font-family: impact; font-size: 90px; list-style: none;}
        .div3{
    float:right;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-right: 500px;



    }
    a { color: #fff;}
    a:hover{color:orange; font-size: 100px;}
    </style>
```

**HTML:**

```
  </head>

    <body background="NEWW.png">
this is my HTML:
    <div class="div3">
    <UL>

    <LI><a href="color.html">HOME</a></LI>
    <LI><a href="layout.html">ARTICLES</a></LI>
    <LI><a href="myform.html">CONTACT </a></LI>

    <UL>
    <div>
    <div class="imageBox">
    <div class="imageInn">
        <img src="aboutx.png">
    </div>
    <div class="hoverImg">
        <img src="about.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

I want my About Button to be on the top right side without moving the navigation bar anywhere.
i have been trying to figure out this for the whole day.

Comment: there is no button in the mark-up?

Comment: can you create a JSFiddle please

Answer (score 0):

Try position: absolute; top: 5px; right: 5px; for the element you want to position.
You should use  to create a button and style as needed with css.